# Password validation regular expression special character

Tags: javascript, passwords

I want to use following code for password validation of at lest one character,number, upper case and lower case character

```
function fd3() {
    alert("hii");
    var v1 = document.getElementById("h3").value,
        pass = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_@#$%^&*]+$)/;

    if(!pass.test(v1)) {
        alert("Wrong Password");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, and what is your question?

Comment: i want to validate password field with at least one upper and lower case character,number and special character . I am groupping whole requirement but not getting output...

Comment: You should edit your question to include all the information - you don't say in the question what the problem is.  Also I don't understand what "groupping whole requirement but not getting output" means.  If you want to get an answer from someone you shouldn't expect them to run the example to find what the problem is.

Comment: for checking requirement of password , I am using /^([a-zA-Z0-9_@#$%^&*]+$)/; but its not validating passowrd for correct result like Abc@123

Comment: I have another question that /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$  <-Here what ? = . * means

Comment: Please don't ask another question in a comment, and I think you should really read a tutorial on regular expressions, rather than asking questions about individual characters in a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking it does match your example of Abc@123.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Follow this link to see it matching Abc@123](https://www.debuggex.com/r/N6CV15AJZERazq9g)

However it doesn't do anything like what you think it does - it will match one or more character in that group - so simply "A" alone will match it.

You need something MUCH more complex like this:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo of the working example](https://www.debuggex.com/r/QJhYwhj9KnCKbv7x)

I would also note that you did not have a requirement for a minimal number of characters so I did not include this in the regex.  My list of special characters in this regex is also different from yours, but that can easily be changed by you if that is important.